# "Error retrieving consenter of type: etcdraft" when trying to set up Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I did the following the instructions in the manual when trying to set up Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.7 and having cloned [the samples from GitHub](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) and used the `first-network` starting point. At first, I got the expected output: (I removed all the references to EtcdRaft in `configtx.yaml`)

```
rm -r channel-artifacts/*
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
```

Now docker is up and I try this:

```
docker logs orderer.example.com
```

And after normal output, I get this:

```
2020-06-16 18:08:47.746 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newChainSupport -> PANI 008 Error retrieving consenter of type: etcdraft
panic: Error retrieving consenter of type: etcdraft

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000ec580, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x546
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc000240070, 0x4, 0x156734e, 0x26, 0xc000347b30, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0x100
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(...)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(...)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.newChainSupport(0xc000172000, 0xc00054a060, 0xc0003205d0, 0x16c8800, 0x208ffe0, 0xc000324540, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/chainsupport.go:69 +0xa06
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.(*Registrar).Initialize(0xc000172000, 0xc0003205d0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:168 +0x252
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.initializeMultichannelRegistrar(0xc0003b8b80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0002065a0, 0x2021b00, 0xc0003ee0e0, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc0003ee0f0, ...)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:681 +0x4a5
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Start(0x1543ab2, 0x5, 0xc0002c2480)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:189 +0xa94
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:91 +0x208
main.main()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```

But there is no more reference to EtcdRaft anywhere that I can find. What's going on?

EDIT:

Trying to add EtcdRaft creates this error instead:

```
2020-06-17 01:10:40.083 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] Initialize -> INFO 00e Starting system channel 'byfn-sys-channel' with genesis block hash fbbc5d4bd63c38a9623fb3c3d68493d8441d3de4e249d9a8cabba0619978c56d and orderer type etcdraft
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0xfaee39]
```

EDIT:

I tried it with Hyperledger Fabric version 2.1, which requires Raft, and I get the same error from Raft as above.

EDIT:

For the sake of completeness, here's the full log of [the log for the orderer for Hyperledger 1.4.7](https://pastebin.com/yKvBgFsr) and [the full log for the orderer Hyperledger 2.1.0](https://pastebin.com/cpwiFDBB).

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the panic:

`Error retrieving consenter of type: etcdraft`

This can generally be attributed to one of two things.

1. You are using Fabric v1.4.0, rather than v1.4.1+.  Raft ordering [was introduced in v1.4.1](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/whatsnew.html), which is often a topic of confusion.
2. You have specified a Genesis Type of `None` and are using a version of Fabric prior to v2.2.0 which at the time of this writing is unreleased.  This bug is documented as [FAB-17774](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17774) and [should be included as part of v2.2.0.](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/pull/1197)

If you ensure that the images you are using are current, and that genesis type is not set to none, I expect your errors will go away.

If on the other hand, you are attempting to use some consensus type other than etcdraft (which, for new deployments etcdraft is the recommended consensus type), then ensure that [the consensus type in your configtx.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/2fdbafbed9fc1213a28e5980b8c334ce04c27dcb/sampleconfig/configtx.yaml#L261) has been set to the appropriate type, for instance 'solo'.  Ensure that all artifacts, including any volumes persisted by your docker compose have been deleted, and try again.

Comment: I should have specified, I'm using version 1.4.7 .

Comment: If I try `configtxgen --version`, I get: `configtxgen:
 Version: 1.4.7
 Commit SHA: e0afaa741
 Go version: go1.13.9
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64`

Comment: My consensus type was meant to be "solo", until I tried EtcdRaft as a last resort, but no matter how much I deleted, the contents of `crypto-config `, of `channel-artifacts`, every docker image and network, I still found that my "First network", as cloned from GitHub, wanted EtcdRaft.

Comment: If you are using docker-compose, then it's the image version you need to be concerned with.  So you would need to execute `peer version` or `orderer version` from inside one of the containers.  Are you certain you are deleting the docker volumes? `docker volume list` and `docker volume rm` can help you here.

Comment: I'm using the commands provided in the guide to delete everything every time, but I have not found how to select the correct image. It seems that both the images for 1.4.7 and for "latest" are downloaded and "latest" always has etrdraft no matter what. Currently, I'm using GNU screen, I have 2.1 on one screen and 1.4.7 on another. I don't run both at the same time, of course, but I'm ready to execute either whenever I can figure out how to get either to work. When I used etcdraft, only the first orderer fails. The other ones work as intended according to the logs.

Comment: On my 1.4.7 install, my image version is 2.1.1. That's definitely the problem. Running `peer version` from inside the `cli` image gives `Version: 2.1.1`.

Comment: I set `export IMAGE_TAG=1.4.7` and deleted the volumes. Now the image as seen from the inside is 1.4.7 but I still get the same error. I'll try with the 2.1 version.

Comment: Same error on 2.1.0 as well after setting the `IMAGE_TAG` environment variable.

Comment: If you are seeing success with some OSNs, but not others, then the problem you are seeing is almost definitely a cleanup/environment issue.  I'd try comparing the working to the non-working OSNs to identify what's different about them.  Check their environment, their binary versions, their config files.  Compare their logs during startup.  Hopefully something will stand out.

Comment: No matter what I do, I always get the same error: "Error retrieving consenter of type: etcdraft" without EtcdRaft on 1.4.7 and "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" with EtcdRaft on 1.4.7 or on 2.1.0, which requires Raft. I'm sure the image is now correct, but the error never changes. It must be something big and obvious. I'll look some more. The 2.1.0 version was a new clone in a new directory, although Docker must keep all of its images together.

Comment: I added the full log for each version in the main post. Maybe there's something relevant I didn't include. They're in a pastebin. I don't want to make a post full of interminable logs.

Comment: In your log output, you can see:

"34m2020-06-17 19:58:49.414 UTC [orderer.common.server] extractSysChanLastConfig -> INFO 003[0m Not bootstrapping because of 2 existing channels"

This indicates that things are not being properly cleaned up, and there is an existing ledger causing you problems.  The v1.4.7 log is very strange, and if you have the option, I would pursue v2.1.1 as there are bugfixes.  Make sure that you are using v2.1.1 versions of `configtxgen` to generate your bootstrap block.

Comment: I'm on 2.1.0. I'll try 2.1.1. I really need this working. I saw the 2 channels thing for 1.4.7, but since it was not in an error or warning line, I thought it was not important. I had cleaned everything up: deleted the channel artifacts, the crypto config, the docker images, pruned the networks, and restarted the docker service. I'm not sure what more I could have done. But it does look like things are lingering in general. I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: I tried 2.1.1 and I get the same error: https://pastebin.com/cYAQizeQ

Comment: [34m2020-06-18 19:46:09.437 UTC [orderer.common.server] extractSysChanLastConfig -> INFO 004[0m Not bootstrapping because of 2 existing channels

This indicates you are still not properly cleaning the environment.  There is an old ledger, make sure you delete the volumes every time.